# Core data is causing the iPhone crash

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I don't have a problem in saving the data onto the Core Data.
my problem is in that vc that I'm supposed to fetch the data.

**CoreData**

```
@objc(ItemInCard)
public class ItemInCard: NSManagedObject {

}
```

**FETCH**

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<ItemInCard> = ItemInCard.fetchRequest()
    do
    {
        let itemIncard = try  PersistanceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.item = itemIncard
        self.Tableview.reloadData()
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

**table view**

```
var item = [ItemInCard]()
    //MARK: - Table view
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    print("=======")
    print(item)
    return item.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShoppingCardCell") as? ShppingCellCustomTableViewCell


    cell!.textLabel?.text = item[indexPath.row].productTitleCore

    self.Tableview.reloadData()
    return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 180
}
```

as long as that vc is open in the app it prints the core data(I added the print to check What is going on

**it keeps printing the core data below**

```
[<ItemInCard: 0x281a4efd0> (entity: ItemInCard; id: 0x87c125f9e2c25dff <x-coredata://139AE9B3-30B6-4857-8313-456481AF833C/ItemInCard/p1> ; data: {
    paymentTypeCore = "\U0648\U0627\U0631\U064a\U0632\U064a";
    priceCore = 10000;
    priceTypeCore = "\U0639\U0627\U062f\U06cc-test";
    productTitleCore = "\U062c\U0648 \U0627\U06a9\U0631\U0627\U06cc\U0646 \U0628\U0646\U062f \U0627\U0645\U0627\U0645 \U062a\U062d\U0648\U06cc\U0644 \U0645\U0647\U0631\U
```

but I only have one data in the app. also the table is not populated too

Comment: Offtopic: rename TableView to tableView and change "as? ShppingCellCustomTableViewCell" to "as! ShppingCellCustomTableViewCell"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the call to reloadData out of your cellForRowAt method. cellForRowAt is called when the app needs to reload the tableView. In effect your are telling it to begin the reload after each cell is created so you never get past the the first cell. This explains why you only see one item.

Answer (score 1):

When do you call `var item = [ItemInCard]()`?

If

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<ItemInCard> = ItemInCard.fetchRequest()
```

is called before

```
var item = [ItemInCard]()
```

then you have found your problem.

Calling `var item = [ItemInCard]()` after `self.item = itemIncard` will create a new instance and negate whatever was put into `self.item`.

Also post what `item.count` returns to further help with your issue. Happy Coding!

Comment: `var item = [ItemInCard]()` creates an empty array of type `ItemInCard`

Comment: var item = [ItemInCard]() is the first thing I declared in vc

Comment: when I'm saving the data to core Data I do this too::    vc.item.append(itemInCard)

Comment: Can you post what `item.count` returns?

Answer (score 1):

Do not invoke `tableView.reloadData()` in `cellForRowAt` method. Because it will cause the tableView to reload every time it tries to load a cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShoppingCardCell") as? ShppingCellCustomTableViewCell


    cell!.textLabel?.text = item[indexPath.row].productTitleCore

    //Remove or comment this line self.Tableview.reloadData()
    self.Tableview.reloadData()
    return cell!
}
```